# Salesforce ApexClass Deployment from Sandbox to Production

Tags: api, deployment, salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm trying to deploy Apex class from the sandbox to Production.
But I get a code coverage error.

My code coverage is 69% I don't know how to increase it to 75%. but my code works fine on the sandbox.

Please help me with it.

My code is:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/TestAPI')

global with sharing class TestingAPI {   
    @HttpPost
    global static string doPost(string company, string first_name)
    {
        Lead objLead = new Lead();
        objLead.Company = company;
        objLead.FirstName = first_name;

   
        insert objLead; 
        return 'Submitted Successfully';
        
  
        
    }  
}
```

Comment: Hi Waheed,
Unfortunately, the fact that the code or code + tests work fine in a sandbox is not proof of anything when it comes to deploying what you have done...
You do need to share your test class beside the actual code so that we can comment...

Answer (score 0):

Per [this answer](https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000hwz9AAA), the standard required fields on the Lead object are Company, LastName and Status, so I had to change your class slightly. I also moved the returned string to a constant to make it available in the test class as well.

```java
@RestResource(urlMapping='/TestAPI')
global with sharing class TestingAPI {

    public static final String SUCCESS_MSG = 'Submitted Successfully';

    @HttpPost
    global static string doPost(String company, String lastName) {
        Lead objLead = new Lead();
        objLead.Company = company;
        objLead.LastName = lastName;

        insert objLead;
        return SUCCESS_MSG;
    }
}
```

A test class for this could look something like the following (100% coverage):

```java
@IsTest
public class TestingAPITest {

    @IsTest
    static void test_doPost() {
        String company = 'Test Company';
        String lastName = 'TestName';
        String returnedStr = TestingAPI.doPost(company, lastName);

        System.assertEquals(TestingAPI.SUCCESS_MSG, returnedStr);

        Lead testLead = [
            SELECT Company, LastName
            FROM Lead
            LIMIT 1
        ];

        System.assertEquals(company, testLead.Company);
        System.assertEquals(lastName, testLead.LastName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please add `Test.startTest();` and `Test.stopTest();` at the correct place ? Just to follow best practices of testing ?

Comment: I agree that that using the start() and stop() methods is a best practice. However, the OP seems like a new Apex developer and I didn't want to add more complexity to my answer.